# Use Cursor Value for a Query inside Cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

I'd like to persist some Views we have on DB Server A into fixed tables in DB Server B.
My plan is as follow:
I get all Views from DB Server A and write it into a helper-table in DB Server B.

Then I create a Cursor, to execute following query for each cursor value: "select * into DBServerB.dbo.@CursorValue from DBServerA.dbo.@CursorValue"

My current code looks like this:

```
 declare @tView as nvarchar(128)


 DECLARE CursorViews CURSOR local fast_forward
    for
    select [name] from dbo.TablesforImport


Open CursorViews

fetch next from CursorViews into @tView
while (@@fetch_status = 0)
Begin
'Select * into [DBServerB].[DB].dbo.'+@tView +' FROM [DBServerA].[DB].[dbo].'+ @tView
fetch next from CursorViews into @tView
end;
close CursorViews
deallocate CursorViews
```

Currently im struggling to get the query work. Any ideas?  :)

Comment: Don't inject raw, unsanitised variables/parameters into your dynamic statements. **Always** properly quote your dynamic objects. [Dos and Don'ts of Dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dos-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql)

Comment: It is not enough to say "you struggle". Is there an error? If so, post it - all of it. The first statement in the loop is simply a string that you attempt to build. You do nothing with it - even if it were valid syntax. Step one is to validate the loop logic and the dynamic sql statement you are attempting to build. So just add "set @sql = " to the beginning of that line (after declaring that variable). Then add "select @sql;" as the following line and run the code to validate the logic.

Comment: But you really need to find a tutorial on dynamic sql - so maybe [Erland's discussion](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) will help. This is not a topic for beginners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT
        name
    FROM
        TablesforImport
    OPEN cur;

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @name;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    set @sql= 'SELECT * into [DBServerB].[DB].dbo.[' + @name + '] FROM [DBServerA].[DB].dbo.[' + @name + ']'

    exec sp_executesql @sql

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @name;
end
close cur
deallocate cur
```

Comment: Hello - Thank you, but this is what i already do.. so it's not really helpfull for me :(

Comment: @rdkli: Sorry for that.
Is any error returned? My first guess would be to wrap [] around your used variable to tell SQL server this is going to be a database object.

Comment: @rdkli putting the comments regarding Do's and Don'ts aside (depends on you) I updated my answer. Worked for me..

Comment: ^Hi Dominik! yep, the solution was to put the whole query into a variable and run it with exec sp_executesql  ! Thank you!